# Log in as unix user using password stored in htpasswd

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, pam, vsftpd

I know this is possible to log in vsftpd using htpasswd (libpam-pwdfile) but in every tutorials I read, they use virtual user.

My users are not virtual, they are local user I added using "adduser" command, I would like to allow them to log into the FTP server, but using password stored in htpasswd.

How can I do that ? Does this feature only works with virtual users ?

Comment: Would a script which dynamically adds them to `/etc/passwd` also help?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Will it use the password stored in my .htpasswd file after that ? Because otherwise it will use the password stored in  "/etc/shadow"